# Number of solutions of the congruence $x^2-x=yz\pmod{p^n}.$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be any prime, and $n$ any positive integer. How many solutions (triples $(x,y,z)$) does the following congruence have:
$$x^2-x=yz\pmod{p^n}.$$
For $n=1$ one can check that there are $p^2+p$ solutions. Is it possible to find the number of solutions when $n>1$?

Comment: to increase $n$ from 1 to 2, fix one of your symbolic solutions $(x,y,z)$ for $n=1$  and, well, discuss $(x+pr,y+ps,z+pt)$  and your congruence $\pmod{p^2}.$  If there is just one triple (r,s,t) for each base triple (x,y,z) then the count has not increased; this is what happens with the square of just one variable.

Comment: appears you will need one answer over and over: given $a,b,c \neq 0 \pmod p,$ and variables called $r,s,t,$ how many solutions are there to $ar+bs+ct \equiv 0 \pmod p \; ? \; $  I get $p^2,$ which may be the factor by which your count increases when increasing exponent $n$ by $1$